# blank screen appear few millisec before uiwebview display local HTML page

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController that display a table view. When I click on a row then I push a new view on the stack that contains a UIWebView.
Inside the View Controller I load a local HTML page in the UIWebView. It works fine except that the first time the app is started when the UIWebView is displayed there is a blank white screen that is pushed during 1 sec before to really display the HTML content.
Next times the blank white screen is displayed also but only few millisecond.

How can I do to avoid this blank white screen before the HTML is displayed?
Here's the code I'm using to display the HTML file in the uiWebView.

```
    NSString *localizedAboutHTML = NSLocalizedString(@"About", @"Filename of the HTML page to be displayed depending on the language");
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:localizedAboutHTML ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL* baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
                  [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

webView.opaque = YES;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

Thanks,

Séb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because WebView loading can take longer, depends on your HTML file. If you don't want to show white screen appears for that short period of time why not Add activity indicator to show that webview is loading for users. One more option is hide webView and show it after webView loading is complete in webview delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just implemented the delegate UIWebDelegate with the method webViewDidFinishLoad and it works perfectly. I don't need to Add an activity indicator because my page is loaded quite fast because it's an HTML file embedded in my App.